# Is it possible to have separate DHT tabes?

Tags: bittorrent, dht, kademlia

I'm getting familiar with `DHT` and I mostly understand how it works. However, I don't quite understand what happens if you want to have separate `DHT`s with different entry types in each. Is this possible?

If I use a popular `DHT` library, does that mean I `put` and `get` entries using the same `DHT` as every user of said library? Or is `DHT` universal for everyone? How do you define an `owner` of a `DHT`, or how do you define a separate, contained `DHT`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can actually have unlimited numbers of DHTs using the same protocol as long as peers don't know each other.

This is the important part when you set up a network. You have to know a second peer to intitially create the network. The next peer would have to know one of the two initial nodes, the next one needs knowledge of one of the three above and so forth.

You are also able to be connected to multiple DHTs on the same host without the two interferring (at least in terms of data exchange, not in terms of local ressources). And you are also able to joins those two DHTs by telling one of them about the peers you are connected to in the other DHT. Though that might be not as easy as it sounds.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can make separate `DHT`s. However you need to make the 'on the wire' protocols slightly diffrent so they can't speak to each other and get mixed up.